# The Existence of a Periodic Solution in a Non-Homogeneous System of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

Variation of parameters tells us that the solution to the equation $$\dot{X}(t) = AX(t) + G(t)$$ with initial condition $X(0) = X_0$ is

$$X(t) = \exp(tA)(X_0 + \int_0^t \exp(-sA)G(s)ds)$$
where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of real numbers, $X_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$, and $G: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous.

My textbook was going through an example where $G$ was $2\pi$-periodic, and $A$ had only negative (real) eigenvalues, say $\lambda_j$. They claimed that there existed a solution which was also $2 \pi$-periodic, and began doing so by assuming $X(2\pi) = X_0$, and solving the resulting equation for $X_0$. In more detail,

$$X_0 = \exp(2\pi A)X_0 + \exp(2\pi A) \int_0^{2\pi} \exp(-sA)G(s)ds$$
Letting $W =  -\exp(2\pi A) \int_0^{2\pi} \exp(-sA)G(s)ds$, we find that

$$X_0 = (\exp(2\pi A)-I)^{-1}W$$

Where we know $(\exp(2\pi A)-I)^{-1}$ exists because $\exp(2 \pi A)$ must have eigenvalues $\exp(2 \pi \lambda_j) < 1$

From here, my textbook simply states "the solution with this initial condition is then $2\pi$-periodic", however, I don't understand why that is. As I see it, the initial condition we found is only a necessary condition for a $2\pi$-periodic solution, and does not guarantee one exists.

Otherwise, the argument could be repeated with *any* real number $\tau$ in place of $2 \pi$ and we'd then find (by their reasoning) a $\tau$-periodic solution. Of course, these solutions could be shown to not be periodic by observing that

$$x(t+\tau) = x(t) \implies \dot{x}(t+\tau) = \dot{x}(t) \implies G(t + \tau) = G(t)$$ which is only true if $\tau = 2 \pi n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So my question is, what is happening here? Was their argument enough to show that we have a $2 \pi$-periodic solution? And if so, what is my argument telling me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation $\dot x=f(t,x)$ with $T$-periodic $f$ has a $T$-periodic solution if and only if $x(0)=x(T)$.

Comment: So this is to say that the textbook's solution indeed did not imply the existence of a $2 \pi$-periodic solution?

Comment: No, this is to say that your textbook tries (and succeeds) to find a $2\pi$ solution by choosing $X_0$ such that $X(0)=X(2\pi)$.

Comment: You have lost me. They begin by assuming $X(0)=X(2\pi)$, and then find a necessary condition we would need for that to hold. If that method did indeed find a point where $X(0)=X(2\pi)$, then it follows by the same argument that we can find initial data satisfying $X(0)=X(T)$ for any $T$. By your reasoning, this implies we have a $T$-periodic solution for any $T$, but this is not possible.

Comment: No, it is not true. Note that the condition requires that your equation is also $2\pi$ periodic, which is essential.

Comment: While I see what you mean, they made no mention of that nor the result given on your original answer. They simply carried forth the method I supplied and claimed it yielded a $2\pi$-periodic solution, as though the method itself was responsible. I am willing to believe we can find a $2\pi$-periodic solution (and not others) with the conjunction of additional information/theorems. I simply wish to ensure that the method they gave, by itself, is insufficient.

Comment: This "result" has a two line proof, and even in your question there is an assumption on $G$ being $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Once again, all I was asking is whether their method shows that we have a $2\pi$-periodic solution *by itself*, and the periodicity of $G$ is not used in their method. It may appear trivial in conjunction to the result you provided, but this had not been addressed in their proof nor anywhere prior, and I wanted assurance that more work (albeit trivial) was needed to make the full conclusion. I am now convinced it is, however, so I will close this.

Answer (score 0):

$$X(t) = \exp(tA)(X_0 + \int_0^t \exp(-sA)G(s)ds)$$ 
This expression is not quite right. Think that this DE being linear, can be solved as

$$
X(t) = X_h(t) + X_p(t)
$$

Here $X_h(t)$ represents the transient response which goes to $0$ as time goes by, if $A$ has only real negative eigenvalues. $X_p(t)$ is the forced response. If $G(t)$ is periodic then $X_p(t)$ will be periodic also.